# How to calculate Permutations if you have more places than distinct objects

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm having trouble using a Permutation formula for finding out how many different ways there are to seat 264 people at 481 desks. The trouble I'm having is that in the Permutation formula (*n*P*r* = *n*! / (*n*-*r*)!) *n* would be the distinct people (264) and *r* would be the number of desks (i.e. spots) to fill (481).

But this calculation doesn't work, as 264 - 481 = (-217), for which you cannot calculate the factorial.

So my question is, is it possible to calculate the number of different ways a number of distinct objects can be placed into a greater number of places, as with my example above? Can *r* be greater than *n* in the Permutation formula? And if so, how?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just think of it as how many ways can I rearrange 264 people and 217 "empties"  Something like $\frac{481!}{217!}$

481! ways to arrange the seats, but 217! ways the empties could be arranged identically.

Another way would be to think of it like this: Person 1 can be seated in any of 481 seats.  Person 2 has 480 choices.

$481*480*479*\dots*(481-263)=\frac{481!}{217!}$

Comment: So if I read this correctly, the calculation could work if I think of the seats as the distinct objects, and the people as the "spots" they are being assigned to?

Comment: Yes.  Imagine place cards being handed out to people.

Comment: Well I'll be... I had a tugging suspicion that it could be worked out by just changing my thinking, but for the life of me couldn't work it out. Probably a "Couldn't see the forest for the trees" sort of thing. Thank you so much for the patient and super quick response. :)

Comment: No problem.  It works, as you probably see, because the seats really are different.  Sitting in the front row center is different than back row.